# Does Excel Services Support Macros?

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-2007

Does MOSS 2007 Excel Services support macro execution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel services does not support VBA Macros.

They do support UDFs written in .Net though.

Check out here for a list of all missing featurtes:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms496823.aspx

Infos un UDFs in excel Services... Note: You must enable them 1st

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms499792.aspx

Comment: heh, beat my by 14 seconds :-)

Comment: How are the UDFs deployed? Are they assemblies that get deployed into MOSS somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

No.

I found this [list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms496823.aspx) of things that are unsupported in Excel Services.